# PHP php.ini file in the web public root directory ? is it safe enough

Tags: php

I heard when you want to change the php.ini settings when you don't have access to the php.ini in the root level that you can upload a php.ini to the web-root, is this correct ?

> Another way to customize your PHP settings is to create a file named `php.ini` and to upload it to your web server. This works in a way similar to the `.htaccess` file except you don’t have to add “php_value” at the beginning of the line

if this correct that means anyone who type

```
www.xx.com/php.ini
```

**should see the settings ? isnt this a security risk ?**

Comment: No. There is a [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) which is respected by PHPs CGI/FastCGI variant. For `mod_php` setups you can only change setings per `php_value` in .htaccess, a separate `php.ini` file will be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

I'd stick to using [**ini_set**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) instead of putting a php.ini file up there.

But if you had to, you had better secure it with the right set of `.htaccess` rules.
Something like

```
<Files php.ini>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

The above rule will prevent anyone accessing that file as `www.xx.com/php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

It's safe from people editing it. However it is visible to anyone who stumbles across your php.ini, so it's better to use .htaccess to disallow people from seeing it so readily.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either use .htaccess if on Apache, or if I had to use php.ini, use .htaccess to protect it.